# Как считывать элементы в массив?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Условие:**
Дан массив.
Необходимо вывести его в обратном порядке.

**Входные данные:**
На вход дается сам массив.

**Выходные данные:**
В выходной файл необходимо вывести через пробел элементы заданного массива в обратном порядке.

**Вопрос**:
Как можно считывать элементы в массив не имея изначального его размера? Обычно в подобных заданиях я вводил N, а потом N элементов записывая их в массив.

Comment: Возможно, под словом "массив" имеется в виду `std::array`?

Comment: @maestro в условии задачи подобного не обнаружил.

Comment: "На вход" - это куда? В стандартный ввод? В параметры командной строки программы? В функцию? В любом случае должно быть описание этого ввода, перечень параметров, сигнатура функции.

Comment: @maestro стандартный ввод.

Comment: Как обозначается завершение ввода? Или ввод делается одной строкой?

Comment: @MBo в примере ввод делается одной строкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что ввод всех чисел производится в стандартный ввод одной строкой, то можно организовать его так:

```
std::vector<int> m;
int value;
while(std::cin>>value)
{
    m.push_back(value);
}
```

Comment: Возможен ли вариант без использования вектора?

Comment: Конечно, возможен. Придётся тогда либо создать сырой массив с ограничением максимальной длины и отслеживать фактическую длину, либо создать динамический сырой массив и реаллоцировать его, если введено слишком много чисел.

Comment: Спасибо, именно это было нужно.

Comment: Заметим, что этот код **не требует** передачи чисел одной строкой... да хоть по одному числу в строке, а в промежутке по 100 пустых строк... И закончится ввод только если будет введено *не число* или будет закрыт поток `cin` (например, при перенаправлении из файла он будет прочтен до конца).